# Emacs highlighting: how to deal with highlighting messed up by unusual usage of special characters?

Tags: emacs, highlight, font-lock

**Problem:**

In Emacs configuration modes (e.g. `conf-xdefaults-mode` or `conf-space-mode`), some special characters are used in unusual ways, for instance when they define keybindings. This messes up the highlighting for the rest of the buffer.

**Example:**

The ranger rc.conf file uses `conf-space-mode` which greatly helps its readability. But lines such as:

```
map #  console shell -p%space
map "<any>  tag_toggle tag=%any
```

mess up the highlighting since `#` usually defines a comment and is followed by `font-lock-comment-face` until the end of the line and `"` defines the beginning of a string and is followed by `font-lock-string-face` until it encounters a closing quote.

Escaping those characters is not an option because it would prevent them from defining the keybindings.

**Possible solution:**

The best solution I can think of is to fiddle with font lock settings for those configuration modes to remove the highlighting after those special characters. But I will then loose the proper highlighting after those characters when it is suitable.

A compromise could be to keep highlighting after `#` since this only messes up one line and there are a lot of comments in those configuration files, while removing the highlighting after single and double quotes since those mess up the entire rest of the buffer and strings are not so common in configuration files.

**Question:**

What is the proper way to deal with these situations?

Is there a way to reset the highlighting at a point in the buffer? or to insert a character which would affect the highlighting (to fix it) without affecting the code? or is there a way to "escape" some characters for the highlighting only without affecting the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The easy way

It's probably easiest to just live with it but keep things constrained. Here, I took `ranger`'s default `rc.conf` and re-arranged some of the `font-lock` errors.

[image: example font-lock errors in ranger's rc.conf file]

Let's ignore the blue "map" for now. We have two visible font-lock errors. The `map #...` is font-locking as a comment, and the `map "...` font-locking as a string to the end of the buffer. The first error is self-constrained. Comments end at the end of the line. The second error we constrain by adding a comment. (I don't know if `ranger` would accept comments in the middle of the line, so I'm only using beginning-of-line comments here.)

[image: constraining the first string-delimiter error]

The second error is now constrained to one line, but a couple more errors have popped up. Quickly adjusting these we get.

[image: our example errors, fixed]

This is something that I could live with, as I'm not in conf files all day long (as opposed to say, source code.) It would be even neater if our new "comments" could be included on the same line.

### The hard way

You'll want to use Emacs [`font-lock-add-keywords`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Customizing-Keywords.html). Let's get back to that blue `map` in the first image. It's rendering blue because `conf-space-mode` thinks that a string, followed by any amount of whitespace, followed by an opening brace should be rendered in `font-lock-type-face` (the actually regexp that triggers this is `^[_space__tab_]*\\(.+?\\)[_space__tab_\n]*{[^{}]*?$` where `_space_` and `_tab_` are actual space and tab characters.)

We can override this in a simple fashion by evaluating

```lisp
(font-lock-remove-keywords
 'conf-space-mode
 '(("^\\<\\(map\\)\\>" 1 font-lock-variable-name-face)))
```

and reloading the buffer with `C-x C-v RET`. Now, every time that the word "map" appears at the beginning of a line it's rendered as `font-lock-variable-name-face` (yellow in our example.)

You can make this change permanent by adding a hook to your init file.

```lisp
(add-hook 'conf-space-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (font-lock-remove-keywords
   nil
   '(("^\\<\\(map\\)\\>" 1 font-lock-variable-name-face)))))
```

This method doesn't appear to work for your comment (`#`) and string (`'` `"`) delimiters as they're defined in the syntax table. Modifying the syntax table to provide special cases is probably more effort than it's worth.

Comment: Thanks! I can totally live with the easy way and your idea of adding a comment is exactly the kind of trick I was looking for. Inline comments don't work in ranger's conf file (as in many other conf files), but having that weird comment below is fine for a conf file (as you said). At least, now the buffer is readable. Thank you for taking the time to write such a detailed answer.